# How can I combine a tuple elements into a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

Consider the following code below:

```
list1 = ['1x', '2x']
list2 = ['x18', 'x74']
list3 = [('100p1', '100p2'), ('300p1', '300p2')]

gen_list = [[a,b] for a in list1 for b in list2]

for new_list in gen_list:
    for c in list3:
        print(new_list.extend(c))
```

My target result is like this:

```
[['1x','x18, '100p1', '100p2'],
 ['1x','x74, '100p1', '100p2'],
 ['1x','x18, '300p1', '300p2'],
 ['1x','x74, '300p1', '300p2'],
 ['2x','x18, '100p1', '100p2'],   
 ['2x','x74, '100p1', '100p2'],
 ['2x','x18, '300p1', '300p2'],
 ['2x','x74, '300p1', '300p2']]
```

but the result of the above code is this:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

What necessary correction do I need to apply on my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `print(new_list.extend(c))` prints `None` because `extends` returns `None`. Just print `new_list`after the loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using itertools.product, unpacking and a list comprehension

```
[[l[0], l[2], *l[1]] for l in itertools.product(list1, list3, list2)]
```

or

```
[[l1, l2, *l3] for l1, l3, l2 in itertools.product(list1, list3, list2)]
```

## before Python 3.5

For versions before Python 3.5 you could do something like this

```
[[l1, l2] + list(l3) for l1, l3, l2 in itertools.product(list1, list3, list2)]
```

If you know l3 only contains 2 elements you can use nested unpacking, as mentioned by @ShadowRanger

```
[[a, b, c1, c2] for a, (c1, c2), b in itertools.product(list1, list3, list2)]
```

Comment: I tried this line here but still returns an syntax error like this:


`Syntax Error: can use starred expression only as assignment target`


My system is in python 3.4. I don't really know why this is a syntax error.

Comment: It's a new feature in 3.5 https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations I 'll see for a way that works in 3.4 when I'm at my pc

Comment: @MaartenFabré: Note: To get the exact ordering desired by the OP, you need to change the argument ordering for `itertools.product` from `list1, list2, list3` to `list1, list3, list2`, so that the value derived from `list2` is alternating most rapidly; similarly, you'd change `l1, l2, l3` to `l1, l3, l2` so unpacking matches. [Demo (w/plain loop to match OP's code)](https://tio.run/##RY5NCgMhDEb3niK7KJUyaqFloCcZXPWHClbFScGe3qrT0kBIeA@@JL3pEYOp1T1TzASObpli9Ctj3q2k4AwLqoISUBe0A@oBizp1Wo6HLzYdc1TTlFQ3fdEoJHA0P2Y2Zhm7xwxeSfCmtQYX/qf3Kcfr60J8fNB0D9@GFjODVim7QHwZAdrCbkjujRC1fgA "Try It Online")

Comment: @MaartenFabré: Also, given `list3` is a `list` of fixed length `tuple`s, even pre-3.5 you can avoid creating/concatenating temporary `list`s by using nested unpacking syntax; it's faster, as it avoids the generic function call lookup and dispatch required by the `list` constructor: `[[a, b, c1, c2] for a, (c1, c2), b in itertools.product(list1, list3, list2)]` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7NCsIwDADge58it3RQxtoKevFJSg9uKhbmWroI9elrfxQPIckXSBLe9PCbztk9g48Ejm6RvF93ASFEtxFjq9tJwhkMyoQCUCW0DVXDJE9V0/HwZV2Zo5ymIOukFgoHARz1z3Q3y1i/MvbEjbkImAUssoSycPcRivDelx0zuO3/5Biiv74W4u1HAe18T2qwQ84f))

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I actually used the one suggested by @ShadowRanger as it is simple and straightforward, not worrying about  using the * or + operators for I am not well-trained to use those techniques.

Though the explanations are good and informative. I might as well include it on my personal knowledge base. 

Thanks everyone!